# OpenXml Powertool HtmlConverter lists - extending functionality

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I have been stepping through the OpenXml Powertool HtmlConverter class to understand how list bullets and numbers are retrieved and put into the html but I am a bit confused. All i want to do is add a custom attribute to the output `span` that include the `numFmt` (ie. `<span data-numId='1' data-numFmt='decimal'>1.</span>`) but this is proving to be morethan I thought.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested, I managed to do this and I have  made the code available on GithHub: https://github.com/leoseccia/Open-Xml-PowerTools